# How do I get the original bitmap with fresco?

Tags: fresco

When I load a long image, the ratio of 400x4000, I get bitmap with `onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap)`,but the bitmap quality is too low, I just want to get the full bitmap, not display in DraweeView,how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have downsampling or resizing enabled. You have to disable these options in order for you to get the original bitmap. However, some devices are not able to decode bitmaps that are too large, so this will not work on all devices.